# Class based view - get function is not being called

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-1.11

Trying to use `Django-filter` class based view `FilterView` but I have problems with rendering filter in the template. It seems the filter is not in contex.

DOCS: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration

**EDIT:** It seems that the `get(self...)` function of the view is never being called. I've set breakpoints in get method and it didn't stopped there.

**EDIT2:** It's really weird. Debugger doesn't stop even on line: `class UserFilterView(...)`

**filters.py**

```
class UserProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['budget','looking_for','user']
```

**views.py**

```
class UserFilterView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = UserProfileFilter
    template_name = 'frontend/userprofile_filter.html'
```

**userprofile_filter.html**

```
{% extends "frontend/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="filter">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="results">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But in browser, I see:

```
...
<div class="filter">

</div>
...
```

**urls.py**

```
url('^search/$',views.UserFilterView.as_view(), name="user_filter")
```

Can't figure out where is the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your entire views.py? Including your imports and get method

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some kind of issue with inheritance of your CBV that is tripping you up, due to a `get` method defined elsewhere. We'd probably need to see more code, plus exact versions of everything, to debug.

However, I strongly recommend you sidestep all of this by writing the 3 lines view here - https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-view

CBVs are great for taking an incredibly simple thing and turning into into something that takes hours to debug.